# Как получить заголовок tkinter.ttk.TreeView?

Tags: python, tkinter, treeview

Есть экземпляр класса `tkinter.ttk.TreeView` (в этом коде - `tree`). Мне нужно получить его заголовок (то, что задаётся методом `heading`) - в данном случае строку `'Heading'`:

```
import tkinter as tk
import tkinter.ttk as ttk

VALUES = ('a', 'b', 'c', 'd')

root = tk.Tk()

tree = ttk.Treeview(root)
tree.heading('#0', text='Heading', anchor='w')
for v in VALUES:
    tree.insert('', 'end', text=v)
tree.pack()

heading = ...  # Как получить заголовок?

root.mainloop()
```

Конечно, можно сохранить его в отдельной переменной и потом использовать, но хотелось бы узнать, есть ли способ сделать это имея только сам экземпляр `tkinter.ttk.TreeView`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Через тот же метод, которым заголовок устанавливаете, но без дополнительных параметров, передаете только id колонки:

```
heading = tree.heading('#0')
print(heading)
```

Вывод:

```
{'text': 'Heading', 'image': '', 'anchor': 'w', 'command': '', 'state': ''}
```